# Enable urlbar's "One click selects all" in chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, shortcuts

I hate the "normal way of browsing" in linux that forces you to triple click to select the whole navigation bar content.
I can easily change this in Firefox's about:config changing the boolean to parameter "one click selects all" to true.
What about Chromium - Google Chrome?
Is there a trick or a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy workaround is to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> instead. Then you don't even need to move the mouse cursor to the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just hit `F6` (if you're too lazy to press CTRL+L).

Answer (score 1):

Also <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> it's faster and simpler.